# how to call window resize on window load in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a resize function that when you resize a window to that width the contents within it change.How do i achieve this on window load? I have tried the following

attempt 1

```
$(window).load(function () {
       updateDivsMargins();

        $(window).resize(updateDivsMargins);

        function updateDivsMargins() {
                var windowWidth = $(window).width();
                if (windowWidth >= 2560) {
                    alert("hello im 2560")
                    $('.1').css('margin-left', '500px');
                    $('#2').css('margin-right', '-300px');
                    $('#3').css('margin-left', '550px');
                    $('#4').css('margin-right', '-28em');
                }

        }

    });
```

attempt 2

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
            var windowWidth = $(window).width();
            if (windowWidth >= 2560) {
                alert("hello im 2560")
                $('.1').css('margin-left', '500px');
                $('#2').css('margin-right', '-300px');
                $('#3').css('margin-left', '550px');
                $('#4').css('margin-right', '-28em');
            }
        }).resize();
```

so only when i resize my page then the changes get taken into effect which is what i want.But if i load the page on 2560 it doesn't take in the changes.
So my question i pose is how do i get it to load and resize. whats wrong with my above two attempts that doesn't take effect on load.

Comment: Coz you have put your code in `$(window).on("resize", function (){} )` function

Comment: This can be done without jquery.  You can CSS `@media` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your function outside the events handler functions and I recommend using:

```
 $(window).resize(updateDivsMargins);
 $(document).ready(function() {
     updateDivsMargins();
 });
```

, but css media queries could be better solution if you only have the 2 alternatives as code shows.

Answer (score 0):

Window `load` and window `resize` are separate event handlers, you shouldn't nest one inside the other. Simply define your handlers separately and have them both call the same function, as in the snippet below.

In other words, if on `load` or while resizing the window the `width >= 2560` than the condition in `updateDivsMargins()` is fulfilled.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  updateDivsMargins();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  updateDivsMargins();
});


function updateDivsMargins() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth >= 2560) {
    alert("hello im 2560")
    $('.1').css('margin-left', '500px');
    $('#2').css('margin-right', '-300px');
    $('#3').css('margin-left', '550px');
    $('#4').css('margin-right', '-28em');
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `updateDivsMargins` is best called when the `$(document)` is "ready"(DOM rendered) instead of on `load` since the function deals with DOM elements.

Comment: @Pratheep that makes sense, thank you for clarifying.